# Copying Tables contents of one Database to another from a vb.NET app using OracleDataAdapter.InsertCommand

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

So the rundown of what I'm trying to achieve is essentially an update app that will pull data from our most recent production databases and copy it's contents to the Devl or QA databases. I plan to limit what is chosen by a number of rows so to increase the consistency that this update can happen by allowing us to only get what we need, as for right now these databases rarely get updated due to the vast size of the copy job. The actual pl/sql commands will be stored in a table that I plan to reference for each table, but I'm currently stuck on the best and easiest way to transfer these between these two databases while still getting my commandText to be used. I figured the best way would be to use the OracleDataAdapter.InsertCommand command, but very few examples can be found as to what I'm doing, any suggestions aside from the .InsertCommand are welcome as I'm still getting my footing with Oracle all together.

```
        Dim da As OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
        GenericOraLoginProvider.Connect()

        ' Create the SelectCommand.
        cmd = New OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM TAT_TESTTABLE  ", GenericOraLoginProvider.Connection())
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        ' Create the InsertCommand.
        cmd = New OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TAT_TEMP_TESTTABLE", GenericOraLoginProvider.Connection())
        da.InsertCommand = cmd
```

**Question:** This is an example of what I've been trying as a first step with the Insert command, TAT_TESTTABLE and TAT_TEMP_TESTTABLE are just junk tables that I loaded with data to see if I could move things the way I wanted this way.
As why I'm asking this question the data isn't transferring over, while these tables are on the same database in the future they will not be along with the change to the previously mentioned pl/sql commands. Thankyou for any help, or words of wisdom you can provide, and sorry for the wall of text I tried to keep it specific.

Comment: Do the column names and datatypes match?  If so, for a Db to Db copy as per the title, you need 2 connections and 2 dataadapters.  Fill with one; update/insert with the other

Comment: yes they will be identical tables, just smaller sets of data in the QA and Devl compared to the prod. I'll have 2 different connection strings for the different dbs, but can I use the DA.fill() on a table across a connection? If so what would that syntax look like, I've only ever used them for local data tables?

Comment: Since the DataAdpater is bound to the connection, if/when you are going from one DB to another you will need 2 of them.

Comment: @Plutonix How would you connect the two? And by that i mean reference the other da in a fill statment? would you have to fill a local table or is there a way around this?

Comment: You dont need to.  One dbCon/DA pair reads from one DB into a DataTable.  The other dbCon/DA pair writes that table to the other DB.  The connx and DA are db-specific, they do not need to know about other DBs and connections they are not involved in.  DataTables on the other hand are db-agnostic

Answer (score 0):

lookup sqlbulkcopy. I use this to transfer data between all kinds of vendor databases.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx